# Elastic Load Balancer Solution for multiple apps in different ec2 within same AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have three application one frontend in react, loopback api app and another one Blockchain api. if i have to deploy three apps in three different EC2 in same AZ. What will be the best way to set up ELB? Should I setup one ELB per AZ? All apps are running in different ports. As far I know i have to setup one elb for one port

Comment: why do they all have to be in the same AZ? this suggests to me a too-tightly coupled architecture

Answer (score 1):

The point of an ELB is it spans all AZs, distributing load across all availability zones you have servers in. One ELB per AZ would not be very useful, as you'd have different endpoints.

I suggest you have one [AWS Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) (ALB). Create a [target group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html) for each endpoint, which supports the different ports your application is on.